# Social Plugin [ Like Button ] custom color scheme

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-likebox

Is there any way to change current color scheme to custom for Like Button?

Answer (score 0):

No. The Like button cannot be changed, and it's against Facebook terms to change the way it looks.